# How to include and use connection.js file in node.js application of mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

connection.js

```
 /** 
  * lets require/import the mongodb native drivers.
  */
 var mongodb = require('mongodb');
 var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
 var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database';

/**
 * Use connect method to connect to the Server
 */

MongoClient.connect(url,function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:',     err);
    } 
    else {
         console.log('Connection established to', url);
         var collection = db.collection('users');
         db.close();
   }
});
```

Comment: Bit of advice. Just submitting a raw code block with "no real question" other than your question title is not going to get you much help here. It is also "way to broad" a question without a specific context. I would suggest that if you do not understand Singleton patterns or the node "require" system enough then look at some other "higher level" MongoDB driver adaptation other than the base driver. "Mongoose" ( not an endorsement ) is something that might suit your needs right now.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to just connect mongodb in the app.js, and only keep the passwords or url in an external file. But if you're going to do it your way.

Assuming your instance of mongoDB is running, and you're using the native driver for node, your connect.js should look like this:

```
// Require
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, assert = require('assert');

// Location
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

// Connect
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  db.close();
});
```

Then your app.js will require your connect.js. It should look something like this

```
var db = require('...path to connect.js');
```

Don't forget to include mongoDB drivers in all of your models, then export your models. You then import your models into each controller you use them in.

Comment: pls  tell me how to use var db  to establish connection and insert values in database